# sort by date created php

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date

I have a audio player and its pulling its audio from a folder its currently being sorted by name but I want to sort it by date created. any help would be appreciated.

```
$media = array();

    $di = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach ($di as $fileinfo) {
        $path_info = pathinfo($fileinfo->getPathname());
        if(isset($path_info['extension'])){
            if(in_array(strtolower($path_info['extension']), $allowed_files)){
                $fn = $fileinfo->getPathname();
                $media[] = array( 
                    "SITE_URL" => SITE_URL, 
                    "SITEPATH" => SITEPATH, 
                    "fullpath" => SITE_URL.'/'.path2url(realpath($path_info['dirname'])).'/'.$path_info['basename'],  
                    "basename" => $path_info['basename'], 
                    "extension" => $path_info['extension'],
                    "dirname" => realpath($path_info['dirname']),
                    "filename" => $path_info['filename']
                ); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) only gives access to [`access Time`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getatime.php), [`modification time`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php) or [`inode change time`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getctime.php). If your files have not been changed since creation, `modification time` will be the same and you can then save that time in the `$media` array and then sort the array using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$media = array();

$di = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach ($di as $fileinfo) {
    $path_info = pathinfo($fileinfo->getPathname());
    if(isset($path_info['extension'])){
        if(in_array(strtolower($path_info['extension']), $allowed_files)){
            $fn = $fileinfo->getPathname();
            $media[] = array( 
                "SITE_URL" => SITE_URL, 
                "SITEPATH" => SITEPATH, 
                "fullpath" => SITE_URL.'/'.path2url(realpath($path_info['dirname'])).'/'.$path_info['basename'],  
                "basename" => $path_info['basename'], 
                "extension" => $path_info['extension'],
                "dirname" => realpath($path_info['dirname']),
                "filename" => $path_info['filename'],
                "mtime" => $fileinfo->getMTime()
            ); 
        }
    }
}
array_multisort(array_column($media, 'mtime'), SORT_ASC, $media);
```

Comment: Cute use of array_column.